# difference between pandas methods, data frame methods and how to distinguish between them

Tags: pandas, methods, jupyter-notebook, data-science

It has been a while I am confused between these and I would like to see if there is a way to easily distinguish between these in a practical and fast way.

assuming df is a pandas data frame object, please see below:

while using pandas, this is what I noticed. To access/perform some methods, you have to use pd.method(df,*args) sometimes. To access some other ones, you need to use df.method(*args). Interestingly, there are some methods that work either way ...

Let's clarify this a bit more with some examples: while it totally makes sense to me to use pd.read_csv (), not df.read_csv, since there is no df created yet, I have a hard time making sense of the following examples:

1- correct: pd.getdummies(df,*args) --- incorrect: df.getdummies(*args)

2- correct: df.groupby(*args) --- incorrect: pd.groupby(df,*args)

3- correct: df.isnull() AND pd.isnull(df)

I am pretty sure you can also come up with many other examples as above. I personally find this challenging to keep in mind which one is which and found myself wasting a lot of time in total code development/analysis cycle trying to guessing if I should use pd.method (df) or df.method() for different things.

My main question is: how do you guys handle this? did you also find this issue challenging? is there any way to quickly understand which one to use ? am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Certain functions which are `pd.funct(df)` can take multiple kinds of inputs. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html for example takes data input in forms array-like, Series, or DataFrame.

Comment: I don't find it confusing...  basic rule of thumb a pd.method() typically creates a new object or is a utility function.  a df.method() is always an operation on a dataframe which typically returns a dataframe or series.  If both are available I will almost always use a df method (for example df.merge(df2) as opposed to pd.merge(df, df2) )